# Add single child to firebase databse and display in a listVIew - android

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase project in which I have successfully implemented firebase Email authentication and email verification. Now in my firebase database, I need to add areas to the database for each user.

My code Snippet adding a child to the database (Correct me If I did that in a wrong way).

```
 addBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String areaName = areaNameET.getText().toString();

                if (areaName.isEmpty()){
                    toast(getString(R.string.enter_area_name));
                } else {
                    databaseReference.child("users").child(userID).child("AreaList").child(areaName).setValue(areaName);
                    areaNameET.setText("");

                }
            }
        });
```

ScreenShot of my database.

[image]

Help me in Displaying the Child of the AreaList node in a ListView.

Comment: In the `AreaList ` are 3 childs, which one would you like to display? Or you all to be displayed?

Comment: I need to display all. Adding a child should update the ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference yoorRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId).child("AreaList");
FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(YourActivity.this, String.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, yourRef) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(final View v, final String name, int position) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        textView.setText(name);
    }
};
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
listView.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What should I need to do in FirebaseListAdapter.class?

Comment: As you see, to display those values.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new. Can u explain me in detail?

Comment: Np, you are here to learn. First you get the `DatabaseReference` acording to your node: `firebase-root/users/userId/AreaList`. Than you call the [FirebaseListAdapter](https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/com/firebase/ui/FirebaseListAdapter.html) constructor with the particular arguments. And than in the `populateView` method you find the `TextView` and use the `setText` method, to set the text as needed. Please see, my simplified updated answer.

Comment: Can you give me an example code for FirebaseListAdapter, it would be a great help.

Comment: Please take a look at this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPqBlIn-Qd4). Hope you'll understand better. Keep me posted.

Comment: 'java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{trickandroid.fulllogin/trickandroid.fulllogin.AddArea}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()' got this error... :(

Comment: It means that one of the childs has a null value. The single one is `userId`. Are sure is not `null`?

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0' showing red line

Comment: **userID** is nothing but **FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();**  **userID = user.getUid();**

Comment: And you say it's not null, right? Because `"users"` and `"AreaList"` are Strins and as you see are not `null`.

Comment: Ok, let take it step by step. Are you sure `user` object is not null?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144641/discussion-between-simon-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: I have found the answer... Now my app works fine... thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Make a PoJo class which contain Pre define keys like in your scenario

Name, Phone, area etc

Than pass this PoJo class to your databse on "AreaList" child will replace all the detail and if new key is not there than 
it automatically add new one.Than call below Method

```
 addBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String areaName = areaNameET.getText().toString();

            if (areaName.isEmpty()){
                toast(getString(R.string.enter_area_name));
            } else {

                 databaseReference.child("users").child(userID).child("AreaList").setValue(areaName);      
                areaNameET.setText("");

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I got a problem in that. It's not adding the child, instead, it's getting updated in the same node.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference conditionRef = mDatabase.child("users").child(userID).child("AreaList");
    final FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter =
          new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
          this,
          String.class,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
          mDatabase) {
              @Override
              protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {

                  TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                  text.setText(model);

              }
              mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
              }
```

Comment: Thank you. But I got these error messgae.....    `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{trickandroid.fulllogin/trickandroid.fulllogin.AddArea}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()`